# Spring Batch - best way to validate data load/batch insert?

Tags: java, api, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application that reads flat file CSV and transforms some of the data then writes it to a database. We are talking  hundreds of thousands of records or millions.

I would like to validate, the day after, the # of rows in the CSV matches the # of records inserted into the database. I would like to have this process automated. Currently, the data loading is done by some scripts which push these CSV files to an AWS S3 bucket where my Spring batch application is listening.

What would be the best way to trigger this "automated validation" such that after a Data Load, another service can check that all batch jobs completed with proper exit_status != FAILURE and that the # of records originally in CSV matches DB records?

I want to have some kind of "trigger" such that this entire process is automated. Is the best way to create a REST Controller within my same Spring Batch application, and after Batch Load is completed, use a POST request to hit my own API that query Spring Batch metadata SQL tables (batch_job_instance, batch_step_execution, etc etc) and get the total # of read/write counts etc..???

Would love some input here!

Comment: you have ```@Validated``` at the class definition and ```@Valid``` in your iterative inbound parameter right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JobExplorer` to get the job instance/execution corresponding to the processing of your file. From there, you can get the `StepExecution` that corresponds to the step that loaded the file. The `StepExecution` then gives you access to all counters like `read.count`, `write.count`, etc which allow you to implement your verification logic.